# ¿Cómo evitar la generación de datos, si el array tiene un valor reemplazante vació?

Tags: php

Estoy creando dos versiones de páginas una en español y la otra en ingles.

Para evitar que el `breadcrumbs` me genere las categorías así:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Es](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos De Belleza](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Mediante `array` puedo cambiar el nombre de ciertos parámetros de la `URL` por otro nombre, en el caso de `/belleza/` como se puede observar se cambio el nombre a `Productos de Belleza`, eso sí, el enlace generado si conserva su enlace actual que en este caso sería `example.com/es/belleza` y eso esta muy bien.

```
<?php
$trail = array(
   'es' => '',
   'belleza' => 'Productos de Belleza'
);

 $url = '/es/belleza/perfume-de-mujer ';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value)) . '</a>';
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', 
$path['filename']));
//$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);
array_pop($breadcrumbs);
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;

?>
```

Ahora yo quiero evitar que se genere enlace, si en el `array` cambio este valor: `es` por un valor vació `''`.

```
$trail = array(
   'es' => '',
   'belleza' => 'Productos de Belleza'
);
```

Pero no funciono como yo esperaba, me genero esto:

`<a href="/">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="/es"></a> &raquo; <a href="/es/belleza">Productos De Belleza</a>`

que es igual a:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » » [Productos De Belleza](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Entonces lo que yo deseo, es lo siguiente si yo reemplazo un valor de la URL por otro dato, de la misma forma como lo realice entre esto /belleza/ por esto: `Productos De Belleza` pero en este caso si yo dejo vació de esta forma: `'es' => '',` que no me genere ese dato, no enlace, no ».

El resultado que esperaba era lo siguiente:
*¿Cómo puedo obtener este resultado?*

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos De Belleza](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que te falta para conseguir lo que quieres es añadir un condicional que compruebe si el valor está vacío o no. Si `$value` está vacío, no lo insertes en los breadcrumbs. De ese modo no pondrás enlaces sin texto.

Con ese simple cambio, el código se vería así y obtendrías el resultado esperado:

```
<?php
$trail = array(
   'es' => '',
   'belleza' => 'Productos de Belleza'
);

 $url = '/es/belleza/perfume-de-mujer ';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    // sólo añadir al breadcrumb si el valor del enlace no está vacío
    if ($value != "") {
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value)) . '</a>';
    }
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', 
$path['filename']));
//$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);
array_pop($breadcrumbs);
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;

?>
```

Comment: Amigo una pregunta, si yo deseo ponerle fecha a la URL de la siguiente manera: `$url = '/es/belleza/2018/02/08/perfume-de-mujer ';` que condición le puedo pasar para que omita los números, ahora sería fácil hacerlo de esta manera: `$trail = array` pero tendría que escribir los 31 días del mes, los 12 meses, y todos los años correspondiente.

Comment: Mejor preguntó, es otro tema, pueda que sea interesante para un título diferente, que ayude a futuro a otros.